# How to combine results of two or more SQL queries in one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table "BIRTH_ENTRY" & "DEATH_ENTRY". Both contains ENTRY_DATE, SEX_ID fields.

```
SEX_ID = 1 (MALE) & SEX_ID = 2 (FEMALE)
```

I want to count the numbers of Male, Female & Total (Male + Female) entries done for Birth & Death GROUP & ORDER BY MONTH(ENTRY_DATE)

e.g.

```
|Month|Born_Male|Born_Female|Total_Born|Died_Male|Died_Female|Total_Died|
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
|  4  |
|  5  |
|  6  |
|  7  |
|  8  |
|  9  |
| 10  |
| 11  |
| 12  |
```

I've used this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    (*Query to select born Male*),
    (*Query to select born Female*),
    (*Query to select total born*),
    (*Query to select died Male*),
    (*Query to select died Female*),
    (*Query to select total died*)

SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(SEX_ID) AS Expr1 
     FROM BIRTH_ENTRY 
     WHERE MONTH(ENTRY_DATE) = 1 AND (SEX_ID = 1) 
     GROUP BY MONTH(ENTRY_DATE)) AS Birth_Male_Count,
    (SELECT COUNT(SEX_ID) AS Expr1 
     FROM BIRTH_ENTRY AS BIRTH_ENTRY_1 
     WHERE MONTH(ENTRY_DATE) = 1 AND (SEX_ID = 2) 
     GROUP BY MONTH(ENTRY_DATE)) AS Birth_Female_Count,
    (SELECT COUNT(SEX_ID) AS Expr1 
     FROM BIRTH_ENTRY AS BIRTH_ENTRY_2 
     WHERE MONTH(ENTRY_DATE) = 1 
     GROUP BY MONTH(ENTRY_DATE)) AS Birth_Total_Count,
    (SELECT COUNT(SEX_ID) AS Expr1 
     FROM DEATH_ENTRY 
     WHERE MONTH(ENTRY_DATE) = 1 AND (SEX_ID = 1) 
     GROUP BY MONTH(ENTRY_DATE)) AS Death_Male_Count,
    (SELECT COUNT(SEX_ID) AS Expr1 
     FROM DEATH_ENTRY AS DEATH_ENTRY_1 
     WHERE MONTH(ENTRY_DATE) = 1 AND (SEX_ID = 2) 
     GROUP BY MONTH(ENTRY_DATE)) AS Death_Female_Count,
    (SELECT COUNT(SEX_ID) AS Expr1 
     FROM DEATH_ENTRY AS DEATH_ENTRY_2 
     WHERE MONTH(ENTRY_DATE) = 1 
     GROUP BY MONTH(ENTRY_DATE)) AS Death_Total_Count
```

But as you know this query will return only one row. So, I've to write it 12 times for all 12 months. Well, that's not good enough.

So, please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What DBMS are you using and what does your two tables (`BIRTH_ENTRY, DEATH_ENTRY`) look like?  Is it only `ENTRY_DATE and SEX_ID`?

Comment: you can use over partition by to solve this.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Tables are: BIRTH_ENTRY (ENTRY_DATE,SEX_ID) & DEATH_ENTRY(ENTRY_DATE,SEX_ID) @Cody360c

Comment: @KevalPandya Is `ENTRY_DATE` DateTime?

Comment: Sorry if that's obvious but I don't know what you're talking about. I don't understand. @Pirate

Comment: ENTRY_DATE is DateTime field @Cody360c

Comment: @KevalPandya You can use partition in `ROW_NUMBER()` for example....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx... it is similar to `GROUP BY` but you keep all of your results.

Comment: @KevalPandya Are you allowed to create a third table?

Comment: But it will just giving me the month list. I want to create a query where all these data are printed. For e.g. the query I posted above just prints for 1st month. If I want to print all the months. I have to copy the same query 12 times and change the month parameter. The query will be way too long and hard to modify in future. @Cody360c

Comment: No I can't create 3rd table. Many users will use this query from my website with different parameters. @Cody360c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this query to work using a VERY small data pool.  You'll have to test it to see if it does exactly what you want.

Table format I used...

```
dbo.BIRTH - ENTRY (datetime), ID (int)
dbo.DEATH - ENTRY (datetime), ID (int)


;with cte (MONTH) AS (

    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MONTH + 1 FROM cte WHERE MONTH < 12
)
SELECT c.MONTH
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN b.ID = 1 THEN 1 END) AS MALEBIRTH
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN b.ID = 2 THEN 1 END) AS FEMALEBIRTH
       , COUNT(CASE WHEN b.ID = 1 OR b.ID = 2 THEN 1 END) AS TOTALBIRTH
       , (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN d.ID = 1 THEN 1 END) FROM DEATH d WHERE DATEPART(mm, d.ENTRY) = c.MONTH) AS MALEDEATH
       , (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN d.ID = 2 THEN 2 END) FROM DEATH d WHERE DATEPART(mm, d.ENTRY) = c.MONTH) AS FEMALEDEATH
       , (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN d.ID = 1 OR d.ID = 2 THEN 2 END) FROM DEATH d WHERE DATEPART(mm, d.ENTRY) = c.MONTH) AS TOTALDEATH
FROM BIRTH b FULL OUTER JOIN cte c ON DATEPART(mm, b.ENTRY) = c.MONTH 
     GROUP BY c.MONTH
```

This displayed every month (whether or not there was ANYTHING on it).  It also displays all the information you wanted.

Comment: Just Awesome. Thanks For Help. It Works Perfectly. ^_^

Comment: @KevalPandya No problem! Glad I could help :)